# Jquery select current element in list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to select the current element from the list:

```
$(".card.v1 .buy-wrapper input[type='number'], .coupon-quantity, .product-buy-wrapper input, .cart-item .buy-wrapper input, .card.v2 .buy-wrapper input[type='number']").on("change", function(e) {
    currentValue = $(this).val();
    id = $(this).parent().find(".buy-button").data("product-id");
    console.log(id);
    if (currentValue == 0) {
        $(this).parent().find(".buy-button").fadeIn("slow");
        $(this).parent().find(".input-group").hide();
        $(this).val("1");
    }
})
```

$(this) select all data product-id in selector list and give me data from another inputs, i need data only from current changed input, not all in selector list.

event.target.id return undefined.

UPD:

```
<div class="buttons mt-2 d-flex">
    <div class="buy-wrapper order-1 order-lg-0 mr-3">
        <button type="button" data-product-id="<?= $value->id; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg buy-button">Buy</button>
        <input class="form-control qty" type="number" value="1" min="0" max="100" step="1">
    </div>
</div>
```

This block is also in other places

Comment: Can you please add your html code?

Comment: Updated. This is spinnet, I use this block almost everywhere

Comment: https://prnt.sc/253l7eu
id is returned from all elements on the page, I only need from the changed input, in parent button data-product-id. Your solution doesn't work

Comment: try $("document").on("change", 'input[type=number]', function(e) { ...